# How to delete a pod in kubernetes without kubectl delete pod command

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, high-availability

I'm running resilience tests and I want to simulate a pod failure. Using administrative command (kubectl delete pod <pod_name>) is not what I need because Kubernetes will start creating the second pod before the termination of the first pod.

I tried killing the pod's process from the OS. I was expecting the pod to be deleted and a new one is scheduled but what happened is that the same pod restarted.

Is there a proper way to delete a pod directly from the OS? or is there another way to simulate a pod failure?

Env:

- Kubernetes: 1.21.4
- Kubeedge: 1.9.5
- Docker: 24.0.5
- Ubuntu: 20.04.05

Comment: Unclean shutdown of the entire host node. It sounds like that's what you're effectively trying to test anyways.

Comment: @jordanm Actually I'm trying to introduce failures on different levels (container, pod, node). Shutting down the node means a failure on the node level so what am I supposed to do in case of a pod failure?

Comment: for pod failure you don't necessarily need to _delete_ the pod, you can introduce the failure by updating the container image to a one that doesn't exist which will trigger the `ImagePullBackOff`. There are multiple other things you can do to cause the pod failure but this might put you on the right track.

Comment: @Sibtain I want to see how long does it take for the pod to be recreated so I could measure the outage time. So I think I'll need to use the same container image

Comment: That was not mentioned in the question though :) is your pod running standalone or is it being controlled by a replica set / deployment?

Comment: @Sibtain it's controlled by a deployment

Answer (score 0):

Automatic re-creation of the pods could happen in two cases. You have either a replicaset or a deployment configured. If there's a deployment then deleting it will remove both its replicaset and the pods. You could achieve this with one of the following:

- kubectl delete deployment deployment-name --namespace namespace
- kubectl delete -f path/filename.yaml

Comment: I am using a deployment controller cuz I want the pod to be re-created. But my question is how to simulate a spontaneous pod failure so I could determine how long does it take for the pod to be re-created. I'm expecting the pod to be deleted and a new pod comes up (that's what the deployment controller does since I have set replica=1) but what's happening when I kill the pod's process from the OS is it's the same pod restarting instead of being deleted and a new one comes up

Comment: If the pod process is deleted at the OS level. `kubelet` will try to restart that specific process and the kubernetes will consider that as a pod restart.

Comment: `is there another way to simulate a pod failure?` 
You could test it by the pod `crashlooping` and this also makes the pod to restart.